# Angular 9.1.1 Allow angular component to access javascript outside main and runtime bundles

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 9.1.1 project containing a Typescript file, call it /src/app/somedata.ts, containing an exported const string array, like this:

```
export const SomeData: string[] = [
    'string 1',
    'string 2'
];
```

It is accessed by the main Angular component in /src/app/app.component.ts so that it can be used in the component's html template, like this:

```
import { SomeData } from './somedata';

...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

...

  somedData: string[] = SomeData;

...
}
```

The issue is that whike the contents of the SomeData array are never changed in the application, they change quite frequently due to external policy changes, and by default, any change to the file src/app/somedata.ts would require a complete rebuild and redeploy.

What I'd like to do is keep somedata.ts outside the main/runtime bundles as the compiled javascript somedata.js so that I can simply replace somedata.js whenever needed (of course through an automated process).

I thought I could do this by naming somedata.ts in the projects.projectname.architect.build.options.scripts array in angular.json. And this does cause somedata.js to be generated separately by the build process and placed in the dist folder. However, the compiled app.component.ts code is still accessing a hardcoded string array as it was at build time, so that changing somedata.js has no effect. I can see this by grepping for a string in the array in the files in dist; it shows up in main*.js and, depending on exactly how I code the scripts array entry, in runtime*.js.

I also tried replacing the import statement with a call to the import function, and replacing somedata.ts with a file with the array as json, but it all works the same way.

Does anyone know a way to get the app.component.ts code to access a javascript (or json) file outside of the main/runtime bundles?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not host the json somewhere and access it with httpclient?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now, but I was hoping to avoid that http call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any component can access the window namespace. You can have index.html load a JavaScript file that creates window.somedData. Any component in the app has access to window.somedData. That JS file can be updated outside the build.

Comment: You say thanks with the and accept answer and upvote buttons.

Comment: Adrian, Sorry. I did upvite your answer, but I'm too new to SatckOverflow for my upvote to appear.